# Angular how can i delete specific object from my localeStorage array

Tags: angular, typescript

I am saving and getting my form value from localeStorage. when i am displaying data from it i want to remove the specific object i clicked on. my code does work but it removes all the data from it.
**here is my policy value:**

```
  "beneficiaryInfo":[
      {
         "name":"test",
         "surname":"test2",
         "personalNumber":"02027041738",
         "phone":"5685522555"
      },
      {
         "name":"test3",
         "surname":"test5",
         "personalNumber":"02027041738",
         "phone":"5685522555"
      }
   ]
```

**.html**

```
  <div *ngFor="let u of user.beneficiaryInfo">
            <span>
              {{u.name}} {{u.surname}}
            </span>
    <div class="del" (click)="del()">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**.ts**

```
  get user(): any {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('policy'));
  }

  del() {
    updateLocalStorage('policy', removeValueFromObject<Policy>(getFromLocalStorage<Policy>('policy'), 'beneficiaryInfo'));
  }
```

**helpers.ts**

```
export const updateLocalStorage = (storageKey: string, object: object) =>
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(object));

export function getFromLocalStorage<T>(storageKey: string): T {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storageKey));
}
export function removeValueFromObject<T>(object: T, key: string): T {
    delete object[key];
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire data from `beneficiaryInfo` array is removed because your `del` function does just that. If you want to just remove a particular object from the array, you need to use the index or the id (if it has).

In the template declare the index and pass it as an argument to your delete method so you can remove from the list the object at that index.

```html
    <div *ngFor="let u of user.beneficiaryInfo; index as i">
        <span> {{ u.name }} {{ u.surname }} </span>
        <div class="del" (click)="del(i)"></div>
    </div>
```

Now in the controller, you can use it like this:

```js
    del(index: number) {
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('policy') as string);

        const newData = {
            ...data,
            beneficiaryInfo: data.beneficiaryInfo.filter((_: any, i: number) => i !== index)
        };

        localStorage.setItem('policy', JSON.stringify(newData));
    }
```

#### UPDATE

For removing the `beneficiaryInfo` if the list is empty, you need to do a check and remove the property by using destructuring (although I think it's better to keep it as an empty list):

```js
    del(index: number) {
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('policy') as string);

        const beneficiaryInfo = data.beneficiaryInfo.filter((_: any, i: number) => i !== index);

        let newData: MyDataType;

        if (beneficiaryInfo.length > 0) {
            newData = { ...data, beneficiaryInfo };
        } else {
            const { beneficiaryInfo, ...partialData } = data;
            newData = partialData;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('policy', JSON.stringify(newData));
    }
```

Comment: Hi, when i delete all the data, 'beneficiaryInfo' still is saved as empty array, how can i remove it too when i delete all the objects from my localestorage?